# Google AdManager getCurrentNetwork() error

Tags: python, soap, google-ad-manager

I have set up ad manager credentials. I'm trying to access the Admanager API, im getting the following error.

```
from googleads import ad_manager
client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage()
network_service = client.GetService('NetworkService', version='v201902')
current_network = network_service.getCurrentNetwork()
```

the error im facing is:

```
Fault                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py in MakeSoapRequest(*args)
   1381         return soap_service_method(
-> 1382             *packed_args, _soapheaders=soap_headers)['body']['rval']
   1383       except zeep.exceptions.Fault as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     41             self._proxy._client, self._proxy._binding_options,
---> 42             self._op_name, args, kwargs)
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py in send(self, client, options, operation, args, kwargs)
    131 
--> 132         return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
    133 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py in process_reply(self, client, operation, response)
    193         if response.status_code != 200 or fault_node is not None:
--> 194             return self.process_error(doc, operation)
    195 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py in process_error(self, doc, operation)
    287                 actor=None,
--> 288                 detail=etree_to_string(doc))
    289 

Fault: Unknown fault occured
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-991c0839fc99> in <module>()
----> 1 current_network = network_service.getCurrentNetwork()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py in MakeSoapRequest(*args)
   1385         if e.detail is not None:
   1386           underlying_exception = e.detail.find(
-> 1387               '{%s}ApiExceptionFault' % self._GetBindingNamespace())
   1388           fault_type = self.zeep_client.get_element(
   1389               '{%s}ApiExceptionFault' % self._GetBindingNamespace())

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing permissions with your configured service account. Make sure the account has access to ad-manager and scopes are configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it this way:

```
class Adx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.GOOGLEADS_YAML = 'googleads.yaml'
        self.GOOGLEADS_VERSION = 'v202111'
        self.google_keys = self.GOOGLEADS_YAML

    def activate(self):
        ad_manager_client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage(self.google_keys)
```